# How to merge branchA into branchB without having branchA's commits show up in branchB?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches: branchA and branchB. branchB requires the code from branchA in order to run, but I would like to keep my commits separate. What's happening is I'll code branchB, then do `git pull origin branchA` in order to get the stuff I need. When I'm ready to `git push origin branchB`, I only add the file containing branchB code, not the file containing the branchA code. But when I look at the remote branchB, it contains files and commit histories for branchA. How do I make it so that only the branchB file and commits appear in the remote branchB?

Comment: could you explain your rationale why would you want that? Why do you have "stuff you need" in branchA, but your branchB should be pushed without them?

Comment: You will have to do a rebase and squash/fixup the commits that you do not want to appear in your branch

Comment: branchA and branchB are two different tickets in JIRA, so I wanted to keep them separate for the purposes of code review. If someone is reviewing branchB stuff, I want them seeing only branchB files when they review the code, and they will review branchA files in the branchA code.

Comment: Why do you need branchA to develop a different issue. Either they're related or they're not.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for, but maybe you want:

```
git checkout branchB
git merge --squash branchA
git commit
```

At least this will get rid of the commit history of `branchA`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing a rebase workflow.

Git rebase replays the commits you've made (in branch B) on top of the latest changes that others have pushed to branch A.

You would make some changes in branch B, decide that you need to update its base (branch A). At that point you would `git fetch`, checkout your local copy of branch A, and `git pull` it. Then you can checkout branch B again and do `git rebase A` to replay your changes in B on top of A.

The caveat of this approach is care must be taken if you're working on branch B with others. Rebasing rewrites the git history and you would have problems when you each push your changes.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `git pull origin branchA`, your git repository is getting the commits from `branchA` and merging them in with `branchB`. Since `branchB` now has those commits, when you push, `branchB` on your remote `origin` is being updated with commits from `branchA`.

To preface the solution, it is important to know that this is not a suggested git workflow and git is not designed to handle these situations well. However, it is possible.

To solve your problem, instead of `git pull origin branchA`, try doing:

```
git pull --no-commit origin branchA
```

This will pull in the changes made in `branchA` on your remote `origin` without merging the commits into `branchB`. It will only pull the files in. It is important to note that you will have to avoid committing these files when committing your `branchB` work.

If you find that you edit the same file in both branches, but only want to commit `branchB` changes, I would suggest looking into `git add --patch`.